# увеличение value input-а при клике на button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим у нас имеется много input-ов и кнопок увеличения и уменьшения значения.
Подскажите скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки изменялся value из того же блока. Желательно без стрелочных функций

```html
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="10" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="20" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="30" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="40" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("increase")) {
    ++e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains("decrease")) {
    --e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="10" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="20" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="30" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="40" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: а если button-ы находятся еще в дополнительной обертке?

Comment: всё, разобрался, спасибо большое)

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, по идее, вот так: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.decrease'), function (v) {
        v.addEventListener('click', dec);
    })

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.increase'), function (v) {
        v.addEventListener('click', inc);
    })

    function dec() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        var input = div.children.item(1)
        input.setAttribute('value', (parseInt(input.getAttribute('value')) - 1).toString());
    }

    function inc() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        var input = div.children.item(1)
        input.setAttribute('value', (parseInt(input.getAttribute('value')) + 1).toString());
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="field" value="10"/>
    <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="field" value="20"/>
    <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="field" value="30"/>
    <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="field" value="40"/>
    <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

что-нибудь такое подойдёт?

```
let increase = $('.increase');
increase.on('click', function(){
   $(this).prev().val(parseInt($(this).prev().val()) + 1);
})

let decrease = $('.decrease');
decrease.on('click', function(){
   $(this).next().val(parseInt($(this).next().val()) - 1);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30oe85pf/8/

Comment: Не просили jquery.

Comment: и это не работает....